# “No matching constructor for initialization of” with vector

Tags: c++, vector, initialization

line 3 (vector::push_back) evokes this error

```
No matching constructor for initialization of 'CCoordinate'
```

when trying to compile this

```
main(){
     [...]
1    vector<CCoordinate> coordinates;
2    CCoordinate * a = new CCoordinate();
3    coordinates.push_back(*a);
     [...]
}
```

However Class CCoordinate does have public constructors

```
public:
    CCoordinate(float X = 0, float Y = 0);
    CCoordinate(CCoordinate& orig);
    ~CCoordinate();
```

What am I missing? Dereferencing objects in vector::pushback(*object) works for primitives e.g. like integers.

Regards
Christoph

Comment: Bad title (and good tag): it is not C, but C++ ! And you should tell more about the compiler used (is it GCC 4.8?), and the version of the standard you use (is it C++11?)...

Comment: OH SORRY, Just a Copy&Paste Error. This is NOT the problem!

Comment: Side Note: Drop that memory leak CCoordinate * a = new CCoordinate(); and make the next line coordinates.push_back(CCoordinate());

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The copy constructor should get the parameter by `const` reference:

```
CCoordinate(const CCoordinate& orig);
```

This will allow constructor of new objects from temporaries.

You also don't need any dynamic allocation, just write

```
coordinates.push_back(CCoordinate());
```

Comment: THANK you! Const was the problem ... which is obvious now that I know. Dynamical allocation was just because I could not figure out the problem. .. You guys ROCK!

Comment: "This will allow constructor of new objects from temporaries" is not the problem. The problem is that `push_back`'s formal argument is reference to `const`, which is passed to the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

This is error as there is no default constructor. Please define a default constructor of `CCoordinate`. As soon as you add a default constructor, remove default argument from this parameterized constructor. Otherwise, it will give you ambiguous function error in some case.

In default constructor, initialize it with 0.

Comment: Can't `CCoordinate(float X = 0, float Y = 0)` act as a default constructor?

Comment: Not in every case. Try allocating an array of CCoordinate with new operator.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe it **is** a default constructor, not just "acts" like one. The definition of a default constructor is one that can be called with no parameters.

Comment: I can't even remove the parameters since the rest of the code woulnt work anymore. Answer was above, const in copy constructor

Comment: You do not need to remove parameter. Just define a default constructor and remove `default parameters`.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: I am still correct. You just try allocating an array of CCoordinate with new operator.

Comment: @dbasic: regarding "You just try allocating an array of CCoordinate with new operator", if that's what's needed to teach you, then OK. Here's an [example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1e496ed0170d428a). Why could you not try that yourself?